# How to get all rows from one table which have all relations?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables:

```
companies (id, name)
union_products (id, name)
products (id, company_id, union_product_id, price_per_one_product)
```

I need to get all companies which have products with union_product_id in (1,2) and total price of products (per company) is less than 100.

What I am trying to do now:

```
select * from "companies" where exists
    (
    select id from "products"
             where "companies"."id" = "products"."company_id"
               and "union_product_id" in (1, 2)
             group by id
             having COUNT(distinct union_product_id) = 2 AND SUM(price_per_one_product) < 100
)
```

The problem I stuck with is that I'm getting 0 rows from the query above, but it works if I'll change `COUNT(distinct union_product_id) = 2` to 1.

DB fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iRjfzJe2MTmnwEcDXuJoxn/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to join the three tables as the following:

```
SELECT C.id, C.name FROM 
products P JOIN union_products U
ON P.union_product_id=U.id
JOIN companies C
ON P.company_id=C.id
WHERE P.union_product_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY C.id, C.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT P.union_product_id) = 2 AND
       SUM(P.price_for_one_product) < 100
ORDER BY C.id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SFvBtNDi?hide=16).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name FROM "companies" c 
JOIN "products" p ON c.id = p.company_id 
WHERE union_product_id IN (1, 2) AND price_for_one_product < 100
GROUP BY c.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.name) =2
```

This would provide you all the company(s) name(s) which has provides both union_product_id 1 and 2 and the price_for_one_product/ price_per_one_product is less than 100.

> Note: You might need to change price_for_one_product with price_per_one_product, as in question you have used **price_per_one_product** but db-fiddle link table defination has used **price_for_one_product**.

Comment: hey! Thanks for your answer. But I need to select companies which have both products (1 and 2)

Comment: I have updated the answer to select companies which provides products 1 and 2 and price of individual product is less than 100

Comment: unfortunately it is not working. You can check it on db fiddle that I've provided. It gives me only 1 company which has both products